# PhpMyAdmin still presents login page even when 'AllowNoPassword' is set to true

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I installed xammp, apache loads fine, but I ran into an issue where I was getting access denied when trying to open phpmyadmin database, so after a little search, google suggested going to phpmyadmin setting and locate my **config.inc** file in where the file config has a line that sets `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` was set to config like this `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'` on phpmyadmin settings, now after some research I found that people who had the same similar issue changed theirs to cookie like this `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'`, which I did, now I got the next issue which is a login page, when trying to login I get four errors.

> ERROR - 1  **Can not log in to the MySQL server**
>
> ERROR 2 -  **mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**
>
> ERROR 3 - **Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.**
>
> ERROR 4 - **mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

I then did a little google search and people said to remove the password, set

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']` to **true** some thing like this **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = 'true'**,

have done that but nothing happened, the login page still appears, is there a way to eliminate this, its driving me nuts over here.

**THANKS IN ADVANCE...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting two different errors here; phpMyAdmin can be configured to use an optional user (called the 'controluser', 'pma' in your case) for enhanced features. If you haven't created the user, you'll see an error message, but you can edit your `config.inc.php` to remove or comment out the lines referencing 'controluser', 'controlpass', and 'pmadb' to disable these advanced features. However, that doesn't seem to be your problem here.

The second error message, about the root user not being able to connect, indicates that there's a problem communicating with or authenticating to the MySQL server. You should try connecting from the command line client to see if you're able to connect as the root@localhost user (which is MySQL shorthand for using the socket connection type rather than TCP/IP networking). You can probably test this with `mysql -u root -h localhost`.

If the AllowNoPassword variable were causing the problem, you should instead see the error message

> Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)